# How to set background color of cells in static table swift Xcode 6

Tags: static, ios8, tableview, xcode6.1

I have static table and I set background color for `tableview -> tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()` and when I have etc. 3 rows in static table then is tableview colored and 3 rows are white how can I fix background color for this cells? This code are not working for static 
    table ->

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell


    cell.textLabel!.text = numbers[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In static Table View you don't have to implement cellForRowAtIndexPath. So I suggest you to implement the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   // Change the color of all cells     
   cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in this case because as you said you are using a static tableview.

Now coming to the solution. Today I just went through the same problem and the scenario was almost same as yours.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor .grayColor()
}
```

One more thing I just wanna tell you that as per Apple's Document all the cell's default color is clear/white. So if you are trying to set the color through the Interface Builder or `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method it will return the white color by default if you are using iOS 7 / iOS 8 / iOS 9. So instead of declaring inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method use the above code. It will work fine.

Thanks

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure each cell has the background colour set to default in the UI mode. under the inspector attributes. Then in the code set

```
cell.backgroundcolor = UIColor.clearcolor()
```

Cheers
Sam

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

Answer (score 0):

you can change the contentView background as it is a subview of cell:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 4:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if _isAccountNotSet {
        print("_isAccountNotSet\(_isAccountNotSet)")
        cell.backgroundColor = .groupTableViewBackground
    } else {
        print("_isAccountNotSet\(_isAccountNotSet)")
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color of an intended row or rows use the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if indexPath.row == 2
        {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }

    }
```

This code changes the background color at IndexPath 2 (the third row.) You could change the 2 to which ever number you'd like or make it a list of numbers like so:

```
if indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 7
        {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
```

you could also sub in a variable instead of the 2 to make it more dynamic.

Good Luck!